# Sending RTP using Java

Tags: java, rtp

What would be the best way to send/receive audio data over RTP using Java? I have read a little about [JMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework), but it seems to be out of date. Are there are other viable alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) is still the canonical source, and it's being maintained by Sun.  There are a bunch of other packages available, though: try [voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki-Open+Source+VOIP+Software).

Answer (score 1):

You can try efflux stack based on netty https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/efflux